# How I find $\gcd(\frac{a^{2m+1}+1}{a+1}, a+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\gcd\left(\frac{a^{2m+1}+1}{a+1}, a+1\right)$$

My answer until this moment is:

$$
For:  a^{2m+1}+1^{2m+1} = (a + 1)^{m+1} - 2a = (a+1)^m(a+1)-2a
$$ where

\begin{align}
(a + 1)^{m} = a^{2m}+a^{2m-1}+\cdots+1
\end{align}
So,

\begin{align}
a^{2m+1}+1 = [a^{2m}+a^{2m-1}+\cdots+1](a+1)-2a
\end{align}

But, I don't know how to divide :

\begin{align}
\frac{[a^{2m}+a^{2m-1}+\cdots+1](a+1)-2a}{a+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Why would $a^{2m+1} + 1 = (a+1)^{m+1} -2a$?  That's almost certainly not true.

Comment: I wrote like this because $a^2+b^2 = (a+b)^2 - ab$, not true??

Comment: Of course  that isnt true.  $a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab$ and $(a+1)^{2m+1} = a^{2m-1} + 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{2m} {2m+1 \choose i}a^{i}$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a^{2m+1}+1}{a+1}
&=\frac{((a+1)-1)^{2m+1}+1}{a+1}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2m+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{2m+1}{k}(a+1)^{k-1}\tag2\\[6pt]
&\equiv2m+1\pmod{a+1}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $a=(a+1)-1$
$(2)$: Binomial Theorem and algebra
$(3)$: the $k=1$ term is the only one without a factor of $a+1$

Therefore,
$$
\gcd\left(\frac{a^{2m+1}+1}{a+1},a+1\right)=\gcd(2m+1,a+1)\tag4
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simple and elegant. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach. Let $b = a + 1$ so $a = b - 1$. Then, we can apply the binomial theorem to obtain the modular equivalence
$$\begin{align*} \frac{a^{2m + 1} + 1}{a + 1} & = \frac{(b - 1)^{2m + 1} + 1}{b}\\
& = \frac{1}{b} \left(1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{2m + 1} \binom{2m + 1}{k} b^{k}(-1)^{2m + 1 - k} \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{b} \left(1 + (-1) + \sum_{k = 1}^{2m + 1} \binom{2m + 1}{k} b^{k}(-1)^{2m + 1 - k}\right) \\
& = \sum_{k = 1}^{2m + 1} \binom{2m + 1}{k} b^{k - 1}(-1)^{2m + 1 - k} \\
& = \binom{2m + 1}{1}(-1)^{2m} + \sum_{k = 2}^{2m + 1} \binom{2m + 1}{k} b^{k - 1}(-1)^{2m + 1 - k} \\
& \equiv 2m + 1 \pmod{b}.\end{align*}$$
Thus, we have $$\frac{a^{2m + 1} + 1}{a + 1} = p(a + 1) + 2m + 1$$ for an integer $p$. Finally, we can use the fact that $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x - ty,y)$ for any integer $t$, to obtain $$\gcd\left( \frac{a^{2m + 1} + 1}{a + 1}, a + 1 \right) = \gcd \left(\frac{a^{2m + 1} + 1}{a + 1} - p(a + 1), a + 1 \right) = \gcd(2m + 1, a + 1).$$

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Check out $a=6$ and $m=3$. The gcd is $7$, not  $1$.

Comment: The gcd is $\gcd(2m + 1,a+1)$ s ... 7.   I made a *lot* of errors getting there.

Comment: Thank you robjohn, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

$(a^{2m} - a^{2m-1} + a^{2m-1} -..... - a + 1)(a+1)= (a^{2m+1} + 1)$ [$2m+1$ must be odd for this to be true] so

$\frac {a^{2m+1} + 1}{a+1} = a^{2m} - a^{2m-1} + a^{2m-2} -..... - a + 1$

Now $gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a \pm kb; b)$ and

$a^{2m} - a^{2m-1} + a^{2m-2} -..... - a + 1 = $

$(a+1)(a^{2m-1}) - 2a^{2m-1} + a^{2m-2} - ..... - a + 1=$

$(a+1)(a^{2m-1} - 2a^{2m-2}) + 3a^{2m-3} - a^{2m-3} + .... - a + 1= $

$(a+1)(a^{2m-1} - 2a^{2m-2} + 3a^{2m-3} - 4a^{2m-4} + ... + (2m-1)*a) -(2m)a +1$

$(a+1)(a^{2m-1} - 2a^{2m-2} + 3a^{2m-3} - 4a^{2m-4} + ... + (2m-1)*a-2m) +2m+1$

[Let's double check that:

$(a+1)[a^{2m-1} - 2a^{2m-2} + 3a^{2m-3} - 4a^{2m-4} + ... + (2m-1)*a-2m] +2m+1=$

$[a^{2m} - 2a^{2m-1} + 3a^{2m-2} - 4a^{2m-3} + ... + (2m-1)a^2 -(2m)a] +$

$[a^{2m-1} - 2a^{2m-2} + 3a^{2m-3} - 4a^{2m-4} + ... + (2m-1)a -2m] + 2m+1 =$

$[a^{2m} -a^{2m-1}+a^{2m-2} -a^{2m-3}+ .....-a]-2m+2m + 1=$

$a^{2m} -a^{2m-1}+a^{2m-2} -a^{2m-3}+ .....-a+1$.

Yep, it holds]

So $\gcd(\frac {a^{2m+1} + 1}{a+1},a+1)=$

$\gcd (a^{2m} - a^{2m-1} + a^{2m-2} -..... - a + 1, a+1)=$

$\gcd((a+1)[a^{2m-1} - 2a^{2m-2} + 3a^{2m-3} - 4a^{2m-4} + ... + (2m-1)a -2m]+2m+1, a+1)=$

$\gcd(2m+1, a+1)$

....

Gosh, really?  Let's try it.  Let $a= 5$ and $m=4$.  We should get $\gcd(2*4+1,5+1) = \gcd(9,3) = 3$.  Does it?

$5^{9} = 1953125; 5^{9}+1 = 1953126$ and $\frac {1953126}6 = 325521=3*108507$ and $\gcd(325521,6)= 3$

Comment: I don't want to tell you how many indexing errors I made getting there.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, this question was annoying me too much.